# Mono - System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSource

Tags: mono, entitydatasource

We have a few Entity Framework projects, that we would love to get converted to Mono for mainly cross platform development purposes (as opposed to running on cross platform machines).

But there appears to be a few things missing on the implementation, such as:

System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSource or EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs

Are there any work arounds to this?

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21618 Sounds like what you posted on Mono repo, but very likely you need to port the classes over yourself, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Entity/System/Data/WebControls/EntityDataSource.cs,f415243b75631237 . .NET Core is still the way to go, and Mono is no longer a platform with big players.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I didn't get a response on GitHub, so posted here. There's nothing official in the documentation about the completeness of System.Web.UI.WebControls so wasn't entirely sure what the status was or if anyone had a workaround. I would love to migrate to .NET Core - but - budgets.